# Input Box in an MFC CWinApp

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, dialog, inputbox

I want to use a simple input box in vc++ mfc. I did created a dialog called IDD_DIALOG1, and added a text box. I added a public variable for the input box and created a class call CInputDlg. Now I use the following code but I face with error:

```
CInputDlg dialog;
if (dialog.DoModal() == IDOK) 
{
    m[nodeTemp][i] = weight;
}
```

the error is:

```
Error   2   error C2065: 'CInputDlg' : undeclared identifier    c:\users\omid\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\shortest path\shortest path\shortest pathdlg.cpp    294
```

what's the problem? can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of the file containing this code (it looks like you've named it `shortest pathdlg.cpp`):

```
CInputDlg dialog;
if (dialog.DoModal() == IDOK) 
{
    m[nodeTemp][i] = weight;
}
```

You need to add an `#include` statement that tells the compiler you'll be using things defined in a different source code file. In this case, you need to add the header file that defines the class `CInputDlg`. Presumably that file is called `InputDlg.h`. If so, you can simply add the following line:

```
#include "InputDlg.h"
```

For more information, please read [this MSDN article about #include Directives in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4.aspx)

Comment: thank you very much, I did it but now I receive another error message:

Error 1 error C2065: 'IDD_DIALOG1' : undeclared identifier c:\users\omid\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\shortest path\shortest path\inputdlg.h 15

Comment: I also added "Resource.h" to my InputDlg.h and solved the problem.

Thank you all with the best wishes

Comment: @user: Glad you got the problem solved. Visual Studio automatically defines your dialogs (and other resources) in the `Resource.h` file; that's why you have to include it. Alternatively, you can include `Resource.h` in your `stdafx.h` file, and then it will be available to all source files that include `stdafx.h` (which should be all of them). Anyway, if your problem is resolved, please mark my answer as accepted by clicking the hollow checkmark in the left margin. That's how others know you figured it out. Best wishes!

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you not include h file for it. Show yours includes in shortest pathdlg.cpp